# Spring injecting one reference bean into another reference bean

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

In the below spring configuration snippet, injecting reference of "SomeManager" into bean "SomeWorker" and "SomeLocal". The reference of "SomeLocal" is also injected into "SomeWorker".

My doubt is is it possible to inject the same reference of "SomeManager" injected into "SomeWorker" into another bean, like here in "SomeLocal".

Problem is if i inject it separately into "SomeWorker" and "SomeLocal" than unnecessarily there will be two instances of "SomeManager" which is basically not required in this scenario as "SomeLocal" is referred only within the "SomeWorker"

```
<bean id="SomeWorker" class="com.test.worker.SomeWorker">
    <property name="someManager" ref="SomeManager" />
    <property name="someLocal" ref="SomeLocal"/>

<bean id="SomeLocal"  class="com.test.local.SomeLocal">
    <property name="someManager" ref="SomeManager" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="SomeManager"  class="com.test.manager.SomeManager"/>
```

Comment: Obvious solution to this problem is not to inject reference of "SomeManager" into "SomeLocal" but while calling any of the function of "SomeLocal" from "'SomeWorker" pass the created instance of "SomeManager" as an arguement.

Comment: There will only be multiple instances of `SomeManager` if `SomeManager` is not a singleton scope bean (which is the default scope for Spring beans).